# How to tokenize unicode text with nltk?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am trying to load a csv into a DataFrame and using it for NLP. I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
df = DataFrame(pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv'))
df['tokenized_sents'] = df.apply(lambda row:nltk.word_tokenize(row['sentences']), axis=1)


UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to process Unicode text with

Comment: Like, `pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv', encoding='utf8')` if your file is UTF8 ?

Comment: Yes the file is UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `encoding` argument to tell pandas how to parse the file:

```
pd.read_csv('1459966468_324.csv', encoding='utf8')
```